Problems on flatlist scroll in iOS
I have a FlatList component. On iOS, it scrolls only with a 3 finger scroll.
Each item on the FlatList, is a TouchableOpacity, maybe the button could be a problem?
I need to make it scroll with a 1 finger scroll.
Here's my code:
   <FlatList
     data={options.options}
     keyExtractor={(item) => String((item as any).id)}
     showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
     initialNumToRender={10}
     maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
     renderItem={ListItem}
   />

and the ListItem:
function ListItem({ item }: { item: Item }) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={item.value}
        style={{
          height: 50,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderColor: theme.palette.border,
        }}
        onPress={() => onItemSelected(item)}
      >
        <Orientation.Row
          style={{ justifyContent: 'center', gap: 8, width: 280 }}
        >
          {options.selected?.value === item.value && (
            <FontAwesome5 name="check" size={12} color={theme.palette.text} />
          )}
          <Typography.Default
            style={{
              fontSize: 18,
              fontFamily: theme.fonts.BOLD,
              textAlign: 'center',
            }}
          >
            {item.label}
          </Typography.Default>
        </Orientation.Row>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }


I need the FlatList to scroll with a 1 finger scroll, like in regular lists we see everywhere. But on iOS for me, I see it scroll with only a 3 finger scroll.

A couple suggestions that could help:

Try using Pressable instead of TouchableOpacity in your ListItem

On the renderItem option on the FlatList, try to use
 renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
         <ListItem item={item} />
 )}




I tested this solution, but continue with the same problem. When I try with any iPhone, the flatList do the scroll only with 3 fingers, but the normally behavior is with 1 finger, lol.

Is the FlatList that you're using inside of a ScrollView?

No, Is a Fixed modal.

In android device, the list (flatlist) scroll normally with 1 finger. But in iPhone only scroll with 3 fingers. I never see that bug in another apps.
